# shell stdout PYTHON processing much slower than PYTHON txt file processing

Tags: python, shell, unix

I am doing a task of parse/processing a "large" raw data generated from unix shell. This raw data needs to be parsed to clean it from some special chars.

What finally I want to do is avoiding the need of big temporary file and do that on the fly instead.

Way 1 generates a big 8GB temporary text file (not desired) but is fast (8 minutes complete execution):
First I generate a temporary raw text file (I put the shell output into a txt file) and then is parsed using the following code:
Execution time 8 minutes output file size 800MB:

```
f = open(filepath, 'r')
fOut= open(filepathOut,"w+")
for line in f:
    if len(line) > 0:
        if "RNC" in line:
            rncflag = 1
            #quito enter, quito cadena a la izquierda y quito comillas a la derecha
            currline = line.strip('\n').strip('\t').replace(".",",").replace(" ","").lstrip(";")
        else:
            currline = line.strip('\n').strip('\t').replace(".",",").replace(" ","").lstrip(";")

        if rncflag == 1:
            if lineNumOne == 1:
                processedline = currline
                lineNumOne = 0
            else:
                processedline = '\n' + currline
            rncflag = 0
        else:
            processedline = currline

    fOut.write(processedline)
fOut.close()
```

Way 2, on the fly directly from stdout (~1,5 hours complete execution):
Is the one I would prefer since I don't need to generate the previous raw file to parse. 
I use subprocess library to parse/process the stdout unix shell directly line by line while it's being generated (like if it where the lines of the txt file). 
The problem is that is infinitely slower than the previous way.
Execution time more than 1,5hours to get the same output file (size 800MB):

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(isqlCmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if len(line) > 0:
        if "RNC" in line:
            rncflag = 1
            #quito enter, quito cadena a la izquierda y quito comillas a la derecha
            currline = line.strip('\n').strip('\t').replace(".",",").replace(" ","").lstrip(";")
        else:
            currline = line.strip('\n').strip('\t').replace(".",",").replace(" ","").lstrip(";")

        if rncflag == 1:
            if lineNumOne == 1:
                processedline = currline
                lineNumOne = 0
            else:
                processedline = '\n' + currline
            rncflag = 0
        else:
            processedline = currline

    fOut.write(processedline)

fOut.close()
```

I am not python expert, but I'm sure that there is a way to speed up the processing if unix stdout on the fly instead of previously generating the raw file, to parse it afterwards once generated.

The purpose of the program is to clean up / parse a sybase isql query output. Note: the sybase library cannot be installed.

Python version is -> Python 2.6.4 an can not be change it

Thanks in advance, any improvement is welcome.

Comment: BTW -- it makes your code easier to understand at a glance for people used to Python if you follow PEP-8 naming conventions. That means that a word that starts with an upper-case letter is assumed to be a class name -- so `Line` and `RNCflag` should be lower-case. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: One place I would start, by the way, is looking at buffering behavior of the program that's actually *writing* your SQL file. There are a few different possible ways that could be harming your performance: The SQL program could be blocking (and not feeding new content from the database server) while it's waiting for the Python script to run; and the SQL program could be buffering content in-memory and not writing it until it's generated a larger chunk, leaving the Python script waiting. Until you've measured where your bottlenecks are, one can't say how to fix them.

Comment: ...to do full-system tracing so you can watch the data flow between actively executing software, I strongly recommend [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/) -- think of it like strace but system-wide and with minimal (single-digit percentage) performance impact.

Comment: BTW, the easiest way to address some of those buffering problems might be to switch from using the `subprocess` module to reading from `sys.stdin`, and then piping from a program that generates your SQL. That lets you use identical Python code in both cases (just changing the usage, as in `./yourPythonProgram <pregenerated.sql` vs `generateSql | ./yourPythonProgram`), and lets you put programs to adjust and measure buffering behavior in the pipeline (I strongly recommend [`pv`](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) for the purpose).

Comment: One final note: The Stack Exchange site best suited to requests for general-purpose improvements to already-working code is not Stack Overflow (which is explicitly focused on narrow questions about specific problems) but [codereview.se]. That said, there are some changes that would needed; among others, whereas we want a [mre], they want *complete and working* code. Should this question be closed as "too broad" here, do consider modifying it per the guidelines in [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777) and then posting there.

Comment: (To be clear, you *do* have a specific problem, but in an ideal SO context, we'd have a reproducer anyone could run, not just someone with your specific Sybase database; and the shortest possible code that reproduces that problem, with anything not essential to testing whether the issue is resolved removed)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy using `sys.stdin` and `generateSql | ./yourPythonProgram` it's been a good solution for me so far. Reduced the execution time to ~4minutes without the need of the temporary text file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if you post the comment as an answer, I can accept it as a solution to the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the ability to reproduce the problem, a canonical answer isn't feasible -- but it's possible to provide the tools needed to narrow in on the problem.

If you switch from using `subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` to just reading from `sys.stdin` unconditionally, that means we can use the same code in *both* the reading-from-a-file case (in which case you'll want to run `./yourscript <inputfile`), and in the pipe-from-a-process case (`./runIsqlCommand | ./yourscript`), so we can be confident that we're testing like-for-like.

Once that's done, it also gives us room to put buffering in place, to prevent the sides of the pipeline from blocking on each other unnecessarily. To do this might look like:

```sh
./runIsqlCommand | pv | ./yourscript
```

...where `pv` is [Pipe Viewer](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), a tool that both provides a progress bar (when the total amount of content is known), a throughput indicator, and -- critically for our purposes -- a much larger buffer than the operating system's default, and room to adjust that size further (and monitor consumption).

To determine whether the Python script is running slower than the SQL code, tell `pv` to display buffer consumption with the `-T` argument. (If this shows `----`, then `pv` is using the `splice()` syscall to transfer content between the processes directly without actually performing buffering; the `-C` argument will increase `pv`'s overhead, but ensure that it's actually able to perform buffering and report on buffer content). If the buffer is 100% full almost all of the time, then we know that the SQL is being generated faster than the Python can read it; if it's usually empty, we know the Python is keeping up.